# Como destruir fragment anterior?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Em meu projeto Android eu navego entre `fragments`, em um desses `fragments`, existe uma lista que recebe informações de um `json`.
Surgiu a necessidade de atualizar essa lista a cada 1 minuto, estou usando 
`postDelayed(this, 60000);` 
que chama uma thread, que usa 
`changeActivity(ActivitiesListFragment.class, null);`para atualizar a lista.

Está funcionando, a lista é atualizada em um novo `fragment`.

O problema, é que quando aperto o botão voltar, ele volta para a lista anterior, pois ela não foi "destruída".

Como faço para iniciar um novo `fragment` e excluir o `fragment` anterior?

Comment: Você poderia usar o backstack dos fragments aqui tem uma resposta, depois coloco uma resposta aqui 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18306258/3861347

Comment: Na hora de adicionar o fragment, use replace, e não add. Desse jeito você sempre terá apenas um fragment.